# Driving an input with a 12V 4k7 pullup from 3V3 logic

Tags: interface, logic-level

I have a board with 12V CMOS logic whose inputs are pulled up via a resistor. It was designed to interface from a board via open collector opto-coupler. Now I have a request to drive it from 3V3 logic. Any suggestions? (I have the one time option of modifying the board, but it must remain backward compatible)

Comment: Use another opto-coupler fed from 3v3 through an appropriate current limit resistor. Or use an NPN BJT instead.

Comment: put up a schematic, 'designed to interface' could hide a multitude of sins!

Comment: @Neil_UK It's just a CMOS gate input pulled up to 12V via a 4K7 resistor

Answer (score 2):

If you want to amplify a 3.3V  logic signal to 12V, this will do that as long as the low-voltage logic can sink a couple of milliamps

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXm3hN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4zFfs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You don't mention operating speed so no idea if its suitable for your particular job but it does the conversion. The inverter and transistor can be whatever's used/available on your board already. If you've no 3.3 V inverters, you can get single gate ICs freely.

If you don't have/want a 3.3 V supply, you can use a second transistor inverter. (Let me know if so and I'll mod' answer.)

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea - I'll try and see how well I might implement it. Since other parts of the system look like they may be undergoing a redesign new opportunities arise. Backward compatibility is a pain.